# How to stop text cursor from jumping to the end in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, has anyone seen this before, or do they know how to solve it? I have a situation where editing a textfield that's in a NavigationStack always pops the text cursor to the end of the field on every keystroke. I suspect it has something to do with SwiftUI's management of views and state, but I am not spotting anything unusual that I might be doing, other than the index lookup in the navigationDestination part. I don't understand why that would be a problem.

Here's some pretty minimal code demonstrating the problem (just try correcting the well-known Shakespeare quote):

```swift
struct CursorResetting: View {
    struct Record: Identifiable {
        var string = ""
        var id = UUID()
    }

    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var records = [
        Record(string: "To be and not to be"),
        Record(string: "That begs the question")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Form {
                List {
                    ForEach(records) { record in
                        NavigationLink(value: record.id) {
                            Text(record.string)
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: UUID.self) { id in
                let index = records.firstIndex { $0.id == id }
                if let index {
                    Form {
                        TextField("Value", text: $records[index].string)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Invalid ID")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known thing, and the reason why you can't use a `Binding` type with `navigationDestination`.

`Binding` triggers the `View` to redraw and it resets everything in the `body` including the `navigationDestination` modifier.

You have to use `NavigationLink(destination:, label:)`

```
import SwiftUI

struct CursorResettingView: View {
    struct Record: Identifiable {
        var string = ""
        var id = UUID()
    }
    
    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var records = [
        Record(string: "To be and not to be"),
        Record(string: "That begs the question")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Form {
                List {
                    ForEach($records) { $record in
                        NavigationLink {
                            Form {
                                TextField("Value", text: $record.string)
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text(record.string)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: UUID.self) { id in
                //Use this for `View`s that don't use `Binding` type as argument.
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CursorResettingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CursorResettingView()
    }
}
```

Anything that uses an array's `index` is generally considered unsafe with SwiftUI so "solutions" that depend on it will be inherently fragile.

Comment: Oh boy. That is frustrating. I’ve been circling the problem of how to organize data and editors of that data in swiftUI, while maintaining proper decoupling of elements, for weeks and this “solution” is the latest to crash into a bug/limitation. I’d love to know more about this issue though, could you point me to any discussions on the known problem? My searches haven’t found anything.

Comment: @CuriousJorge you should be able to find them on SO, especially when people ask about using Binding<SomeType>.self it is a limitation for sure but it goes with the nature of SwiftUI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227263/swiftui-pass-binding-through-navigationstack-enum?noredirect=1#comment132747030_75227263

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have been unable to find any closely related articles on my own. However, I think my situation is different from the one in the article you linked to. I am not using a binding as my navigationValue. I am merely using a UUID to identify the part of my local state that is being used as a source of truth for my child-view. It's standard State/Binding stuff. Furthermore, I know the index lookup has nothing to do with the problem, now. If I just hardcode it to use the first element of my array (`TextField("Value", text: $records[0].string)`), the problem persists.

Comment: Doing further investigation, I know it has nothing to do with style of link (using `NavigationLink(destination:, label:)` doesn't help), and the necessary conditions seem to be the NavigationStack and the source of the binding being a State variable that's an array. I made a new [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75238924) that's much more focused. I think we can scrap this one now.

Comment: I have this happening on a sheet, with no binding for navigation stack, and it's really annoying. On the parent view it works, on the sheet it resets to the end.