# SwiftUI pass binding through NavigationStack enum

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to pass a `Binding` through my NavigationStack enum into my View. I'm not sure if I can pass `Binding` into an enum, if I cannot then how should I go about this. Thanks in advance!

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
enum Route: Hashable, Equatable {
    //ERROR HERE: Not sure how to get Binding in enum or if possible
    case gotoBView(input: Binding<String>)
    @ViewBuilder
    func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View{
        switch self {
        case .gotoBView(let input): BView1(bvar: input)
        }
    }
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
//START VIEW
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ContentView25: View {
    @State var input = "Hello"
    @State var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            NavigationLink(value: Route.gotoBView(input: $input), label: {Text("Go To A")})
            .navigationDestination(for: Route.self){ route in
                route.view($path)
            }
        }
    }
}
//View to navigate to with binding
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct BView1: View {
    @Binding var bvar: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(bvar)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink `Binding` is a limitation of this method, and `navigationDestination`. There is a way to do it but it is very hacky and prone to bugs.

Comment: @loremipsum oh dang, Thank you!! So I should likely just use something like `final class ViewBindingsObj: ObservableObject` and no longer pass bindings around.

Comment: No, you can just use `NavigationLink(destination:_,label:_)`. `Binding` is a two-way connection so that string meant to be changed. If you make the `Text` a `TextField` when you type a new value it would reload the view and dismiss the `View`. SwiftUI is all about Identity... By using the other `NavigationLink` the identity is maintained but that parent `View`

Comment: But, I just changed your code with the hack/workaround and it seems a tad bit more stable than in previous iOS versions, ill add in a second, but I don't think it is a good solution, in previous iOS versions it would dismiss the link at random times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass binding to child view in the new NavigationStack.navigationDestination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584427/how-to-pass-binding-to-child-view-in-the-new-navigationstack-navigationdestinati)

Comment: This is a huge issue imo - thanks for raising the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround, in previous iOS versions this has dismissed the `NavigationLink`, In iOS 16.2 it does not behave this way, I would do extensive testing before using this in a production app.

```
import SwiftUI
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
enum Route: Hashable, Equatable {
    case gotoBView(input: Binding<String>)
    @ViewBuilder
    func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View{
        switch self {
        case .gotoBView(let input): BView1(bvar: input)
        }
    }
    //Create a custom implementation of Hashable that ignores   Binding
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        switch self {
        case .gotoBView(let input):
            hasher.combine(input.wrappedValue)
        }
    }
    //Create a custom implementation of Equatable that ignores   Binding
    static func == (lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
    
}
```

SwiftUI is all about identity and `NavigationPath` uses `Hashable` and `Equatable` to function. This bypasses SwiftUI's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

With the stack, you don't need an enum, you can have multiple `navigationDestination` for each value type. To use it with a binding you can do it the old way, with a func that looks it up by ID, like how we did it before `ForEach` supported bindings, e.g.

```
struct NumberItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: Int
    var text = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var numberItems = [NumberItem(number: 1), NumberItem(number: 2), NumberItem(number: 3), NumberItem(number: 4), NumberItem(number: 5)]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numberItems) { numberItem in
                    NavigationLink(value: numberItem.id) {
                        Text("\(numberItem.number)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: NumberItem.ID.self) { numberItemID in
                ChildDetailView(numberItems: $numberItems, numberItemID: numberItemID)
            }
            //.navigationDestination(for: AnotherItem.ID.self) { anotherItemID in
            // ... 
            //}
        }
    }
    
    
}

// this wrapper View was originally needed to make bindings in 
// navigationDestinations work at all, now its needed to fix a bug 
// with the cursor jumping to the end of a text field which is 
// using the binding.
struct ChildDetailView: View {
    @Binding var numberItems: [NumberItem]
    let numberItemID: UUID

    var body: some View {
        ChildDetailView2(numberItem: binding(for: numberItemID))
    }

    private func binding(for numberItemID: UUID) -> Binding<NumberItem> {
        guard let index = numberItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == numberItemID }) else {
            fatalError("Can't find item in array")
        }
        return $numberItems[index]
    }
}

struct ChildDetailView2: View {

    @Binding var numberItem: NumberItem

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(numberItem.number)")
            TextField("Test", text: $numberItem.text) // cursor jumps to the end if not wrapped in an extra View like this one is.
            Button {
                numberItem.number += 10
            } label: {
                Text("Add 10")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Detail")
    }
}
```

Comment: This resets the view of you actually edit the binding, change your text to a text field and change the number you will see it skip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216625/how-to-stop-text-cursor-from-jumping-to-the-end-in-swiftui/75216851?noredirect=1#comment132730080_75216851

Comment: Yeh the text cursor jumps to the end when inserting a char in the middle, weird.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is all over so I don’t think Apple wants Binding to be used with navigationDestination. The enum way I posted is the most “stable” I’ve found but it is just trickery, I wouldn’t use in production.

Comment: This is really annoying because I just closed a feedback thinking bindings in nav dests were fixed because it worked with my sample. I've added my workaround wrapper View back and it fixes the text cursor bug. I'll submit another feedback about it.