# How to stop TextField from resetting when binding to an array element of parent's @State variable in a NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, has anyone seen this before, or do they know how to solve it? I have a situation where trying to edit the **middle contents** of a textfield that's in a NavigationStack makes the text cursor move to the end on every keystroke. I suspect it has something to do with SwiftUI's management of views and state, but I am not spotting anything unusual that I might be doing. It's all standard State/Binding stuff. Can anyone point me to a flaw or if it's a SwiftUI bug, can they suggest a work-around?

Here's some minimal sample code to demonstrate (try editing the text to say "Hello World" by inserting the missing "el" to see what I mean):

```swift
import SwiftUI

private struct CursorResetting: View {
    struct Record: Identifiable {
        var string = ""
        var id = UUID()
    }

    @State private var records = [
        Record(string: "Hlo World"),
    ]
    @State private var singleRecord = Record(string: "Hlo World")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List($records) { $record in
                NavigationLink(record.string) {
                    TextField("Value", text: $record.string)
//                    TextField("Value", text: $singleRecord.string)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do know that if I use a single Record as the source of my binding rather than an element in an Array, then the problem goes away. (Try swapping in the commented out singleRecord version of the TextField)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't that how `TextField`s are supposed to work? How would you be able to type words if the cursor didn't stay at the end of the string?

Comment: Try editing the text to say "Hello World". I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Don’t use index it is unsafe use the methodology from your previous question, anytime you use index in SwiftUI it is unsafe. The way the List is setup here it has no reason to try and prevent redrawing.

Comment: I'm missing something basic here. How do I make a binding to a particular element of an array, then?

Comment: All the Apple-supplied sample code that I've looked at seems to be avoiding the issue. They often have creation of data, but I'm not seeing editing of data in a Row/Detail type framework.

Comment: what exactly is your question here? the cursor going to the end of the text (as expected with TextFields), or `How do I make a binding to a particular element of an array,...`

Comment: It is unwanted behaviour that the cursor is going to the end of the field when you are trying to correct "Hlo" to "Hello". The user wants to type in "el" to correct the field, but as soon as the first "e" is typed, swiftUI moves the cursor to the end. Ignore the secondary question you quoted, please. I've edited the original code so it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

```
List($records) { $record in
   TextField("Value", text: $record.string)
```

Comment: If I insert a line with `NavigationLink(record.string) {` between those two (and add the closing brace, of course), it still has the resetting behaviour, I think.

Comment: Thanks, though, using $records is better than making a binding to the array by index. I have updated the original question to use your suggestion, though it doesn't fix the problem behaviour.

Comment: Seems it's a bug https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652653 we could workaround it by swizzling _setAttributedTextInRange and setting andSetCaretSelectionAfterText always false

Comment: But first I would check if a new instance of UITextField is being init on every state update and if so then it's an issue with identity and perhaps could use manual ids to fix it

Comment: I checked using manual ids (`Record(string: "Hlo World", id: UUID(uuidString: "62C33AC1-50A0-4A18-9B46-6BA15DE4150F")!)`) and the problem persists. I guess this must be a bug. I don't have a developer account, yet, so if someone reports this to Apple, that would be helpful!